# Is it possible to make the width of flex item equal to the width of it's content (as when you using the "float" property)?

Tags: flexbox

Is it possible to make the width of flex item equal to the width of it's content (as when you using the "float" property)?

Comment: Look into: `flex-basis: auto` and `flex: auto`.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, in fact, it's the default behaviour for a flex-items with no flex properties specified.

The equivalent flex values:

```
flex-grow: 0 
flex-shrink: 1
flex-basis: auto
```

---

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.child {
  padding: 1em 0;
  background: #c0ffee;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `min-width` to the flex-item. If using flexbox you can take advantage of Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing & declare the value to be `min-content`.

**Like so:**

```
.flex-item {
 min-width: min-content;
}
```

You can see an [example here](http://codepen.io/morganfeeney/pen/VemdvK?editors=110)